# Determining the height of water level rise in a combined capillary tube

Tags: surface-tension, capillary-action

What will happen when we fix another capillary tube upon a capillary tube which has not enough space to its free capillary elevation?

[image]

Comment: since $\theta_2>\theta_1$ the force with which liquid membrane pulls the liquid column will be more in the upper tube2 , assuming both capillaries have same radii, the liquid will rise to a total height of $h_2+x$ calculated from the bottom of lower tube , $h_2+x$ will be same as the height of liquid column if the upper tube was put in the liquid alone , you can calculate x from there.

Comment: I wonder what happens when $\theta_1>\theta_2$ , the liquid starts to rise in the setup , if upper capillary wasn't there then it would have made a sphere like mass due to insufficient capillary height , it's not the case here , as soon as the liquid ventures into upper tube , the force value drops, the liquid column drops because that force cannot sustain even a column of $h_2$ height (just for instance) , but as soon as it hits the lower tube, force increases. What will finally happen?